# App Licensing, cant find Play_Licencing folder

Tags: android, licensing

i need a folder that would be present at sdk/extras/google/play_licensing/library/src/com location but there is no folder

i updated licensing library in SDK but still i am not able to find this folder

Answer (score 0):

I also found this issue, there doesn't exist such directory as `play_licensing`.
In fact, below two directories are used:

```
/extras/google/market_licensing
/extras/google/market_apk_expansion/downloader_library
```

Here is [a good example](https://kitefaster.com/2017/02/15/expansion-apk-files-android-studio/) for using downloader library and market licensing modules.